# Multiple inheritance and inaccessible default constructor

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

Why it works

```
class CL1{};
class CL2:private virtual CL1{};
class CL3:private virtual CL1{};

class CL4:public CL2,public CL3
{
public:
    CL4():CL2(),CL3(){}
};

int main()
{
    CL4 cl4;
    return 0;
}
```

, but if I call constructor of virtual base class explicitly

```
CL4():CL1(),CL2(),CL3(){}
```

, then it does not work?
P.S. Compiler is https://ideone.com/HuHlCB

Comment: you don't inherit cl4 from cl1 so why do you need to call constructor of cl1 ?

Comment: firstly, you should perhaps also add the exact error message you get on compilation

Comment: Private, virtual inheritance doesn't really make sense (as you're just experiencing yourself).

Comment: And if `CL1` doesn't have default constructor, it seems impossible to use private virtual inheritance (https://ideone.com/Gbod9I)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CL2` and `CL3` inherits `CL1` *privately*, so everything in `CL1` (including constructor) becomes private in these derived classes.  The former case works because `CL1::CL1()` is called by the constructor of the derived classes. But you can not explicitly call it, because for your inheritance chain, you access the constructor via one of the derived classes (either `CL2` or `CL3`), but  it is *private* in that classes, only other class members can access it.

> Why it works?

Because `CL2` and `CL3` **can access** their private members (including base class constructors)

> Why explicit call does not work?

Because `CL4` **can not** access `CL2`'s and `CL3`'s private members.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't most derived class call constructor of virtual base class? Implicitly call of default constructor also inaccessible from CL4, isn't it? Or this case is custom?

Comment: isn't most derived class call constructor of virtual base class - true but not directly, through intermediate base class. " Implicitly call of default constructor also inaccessible from CL4" - not sure what you meant. In this case `CL1::CL1()` is *implicitly* called from one of the base of `CL4`.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using private inheritance from `CL2/3` to `CL1`. This means that they are *"implemented in terms of"* `CL1`, not that *they are* `CL1` (which is the meaning of public inheritance). You cannot convert the class `CL2` into a `CL1`, and so `CL4` is NOT a `CL1` also.

You can access the members of `CL1` only in `CL2` as if they were private members.

Answer (score 1):

As CL4 is derived from CL3,CL2, so CL1 constructor of CL1 class cannot be accessed explicitly from CL4. Had it been member function, i.e member functions of base class can be accessed from derived class, constructors cannot because CL4 class cannot be converted to CL1.